# Operator overloading: No match for 'operator[]'

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

This class consists of object 'mPoint' which stores a dynamic 2D array.  I'm trying to make it so two of these matrices can be compared to see if they're equivalent.  Therefore I'm overloading the operator '=='.

I'm getting an error "No match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'Square_Matrix and 'int') which points to line "if (mPoint[ i ][ j ] != Par[ i ][ j ])" in the .cpp file.  How can I fix this?  I'm pretty new at overloading

```
//header file
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Square_Matrix
{
public:
   int **mPoint;
   int size;
   void Set_Size (int new_size);
   bool operator==(Square_Matrix Par);
```

.

```
//.cpp file
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "Square_Matrix.h"

void Square_Matrix::Set_Size (int new_size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        delete [] mPoint[i];
    }
    delete [] mPoint;

    size = new_size;
    mPoint = new int*[new_size];
    for (int i = 0; i < new_size; i++){
        mPoint[i] = new int[new_size];
    }
}

bool Square_Matrix::operator==(Square_Matrix Par){
    if (size != Par.size){
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++){
            if (mPoint[ i ][ j ] != Par[ i ][ j ]){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please show the definition of your overloaded `operator[]`

Comment: If you haven't defined one, then that's why you're getting an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your issue here in this line `if (mPoint[ i ][ j ] != Par[ i ][ j ]){`
You are directly trying to apply operator `[][]` on an instance of `Square_Matrix`. Thats why compiler says "No match for 'operator[]'"

You should be using something like `if (mPoint[ i ][ j ] != Par.mPoint[ i ][ j ]){` to fix this. I think its a typo.

Its better to pass `const Square_Matrix&` as parameter.
In your header file change your `operator==` signature to,
   `bool operator==(const Square_Matrix& Par);`

and in cpp file

```
bool Square_Matrix::operator==(const Square_Matrix& Par)
{
    // your logic.
}
```

Comment: Beware that the way your operator is written you are copying the class each time you make the call - that will slow your application down. You're far better off changing the signature to const ref.

Comment: @Foxic - Don't do pass by value in your `operator==` function. This will give issues as mentioned by @Peter R, its better you change the your parameter as `const Square_Matrxi& Par`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to change your `operator==()` as follows:

```
bool Square_Matrix::operator==(const Square_Matrix& Par){
    if (size != Par.size){
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++){
            if (mPoint[ i ][ j ] != Par.mPoint[ i ][ j ]){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Your Square_Matrix class has no `operator[]()`. Also as this is a class member function you have access to the private members of Square_Matrix input parameters - so use those directly. Finally you should make it a reference to avoid the copy, but that also means you want to prevent changes so make it a const reference.

Comment: Error: prototype for 'bool Square_Matrix::operator==(const Square_Matrix&)' does not match any in class 'Square_Matrix' //// Error: candidate is: bool square_Matrix::operator==(Square_Matrix)

Comment: You'll need to change your header file to match the new signature.